# Why does adding a comment change compiled code (object) and executable in C++

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-construction, comments, doxygen, verification

I've started to add some doxygen comments to my code but I see that some comments change object code and also the linked executable in Visual C++.

I used objdump to catch the differences. I expect date and checksum differences but no more. However, adding a comment line to a doxygen style comment on a method changes object code and the executable.

Do you have any idea what can be the cause of this weird behaviour or is there another method that I can verify no changes in executable after adding those comments?

Cheers,
Burak

Answer (score 6):

If you are compiling with debugging symbols, then the comments will cause the line references to move around.

Comment: Thanks but I use release build. Is there a build flag which might be enabled accidentally?

Comment: And if you're referencing the `__LINE__` macro anywhere, its value will change.  How many bytes in the object file change?  File size the same, with select bytes getting modified?